# Python: Group files from different directories with same basename

Tags: python, string, file

I am struggling with a particularly frustrating task.

I have a set of thousands of files in one directory, say `/path/to/file#####.txt`. In other directories I have (probably the same number of) files with the same base-names but different suffixes, e.g. `/diff/path/to/file#####.txt.foo`.

I am trying to group these files together so that I have a list of lists as

```
[['/path/to/file#####.txt', '/diff/path/to/file#####.txt.foo', 
  '/another/path/to/file#####.txt.bar'], ...]
```

It is likely, but not guaranteed that there is a corresponding file in each subforlder, but it's not guaranteed. In other words, `'/path/to/file#####.txt'` may exist but `'/diff/path/to/file#####.txt.foo'` might not, so I need to skip that base-name if this occurs.

My purpose here is to create a file list for synchronized data loading.

How can I efficiently do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended coming up with a solution that's fairly efficient but it does not appear to be the most elegant.

Basically, I first find all file basenames and form a list of lists of all possible sets, e.g.

```
groups = [['/path/to/file00000.txt', '/diff/path/to/file00000.txt.foo', 
  '/another/path/to/file00000.txt.bar'],
  ['/path/to/file00001.txt', '/diff/path/to/file00001.txt.foo', 
  '/another/path/to/file00001.txt.bar'], ...]
```

Then I check for the existence of the file with a given basename in each directory using `os.path.exists()`, like

```
del_idx = []
for i in xrange(len(groups)):
    for j in len(groups[i]):
        if not os.path.exists(groups[i][j]):
            del_idx.append(i)
            continue # Because if one doesn't exist, no need to check others
```

Now that I have a list of indices that are "bad", I just loop through in reverse to delete them.

```
for i in xrange(len(del_idx)-1,-1,-1):
    groups.pop(del_idx[i])
```

This works fine in my case where I only have 3-tuples, but if there are a significant number of paths in the tuple, this would probably break down.

For ~260k files the all-groups construction took ~12 sec, the existence check took ~35 sec, and the deletion took ~12 sec. This is fairly reasonable, but, again, this algorithm is O(m*n) for m files and groups of size n, so it's not ideal if group sizes get large.

Answer (score 1):

My proposed solution:

```
import glob
import os.path as op
from collections import defaultdict
def variable_part(file, base, ext):
    return file[len(base):-len(ext)-1]
def func(dirs):
    base = 'file'
    files = defaultdict(list)
    dirext = []
    for d in dirs:
        local_files = glob.glob(op.join(d, '*'))
        local_ext = '.'.join(local_files[0].split('.')[1:])
        for f in local_files:
            files[variable_part(op.basename(f), base, local_ext)].append(f)
    return list(files.values())
```

Haven't profiled it, my feeling however is that it's close-to-optimal, each filename is processed once, and after the first directory any access to `files` should have been amortised already. Some additional optimisation is definitely possible, especially in the handling of strings.

If the variable part are just integers from 0 to M-1, it may be optimal to have a series of M lists X_k of length N, if you have N directories; Each X_k[i] is set to 1 or 0 according to the existence or not of the file file**k**.xxx in the i-th directory. Only then you produce the final filenames list, removing the need for deletions (which, as you may have noticed, is an expensive operation for a list).

In any case, the minimum complexity for this algorithm is N*M, in no way you can get away from going in each directory and check all the files; those 35 sec *may* be optimized with a single system call for getting all the directory, and then working in memory, but that does not change the overall complexity, i.e. how the algorithm scales.

**Edit**
I was kinda curious on this, and I made a test. Indeed, apparently working on the filenames retrieved by glob seems faster than checking each file for existence (at least on my mac HFS+ filesystem, on ssd).

```
In [0]: def x():
     ...:     return [os.path.exists('test1/file%06d.txt.gz' % i) for i in range(10000)]
     ...:

In [1]: def y():
     ...:     ff = glob.glob('test1/*')
     ...:     res = [False]*10000
     ...:     for s in ff:
     ...:         res[int(s[10:16])] = True
     ...:     return res
     ...:

In [2]: %timeit x()
10 loops, best of 3: 71.2 ms per loop

In [3]: %timeit y()
10 loops, best of 3: 32.6 ms per loop
```